# How to create a custom json request payload for Jmeter with testdata pulled from CSV file?

Tags: json, https, jmeter, request, payload

I need to create a custom Json payload for my script where I need to use the test data from the CSV file.

Example:

CSV file location: C:\Users..\Documents\testData.csv
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKV2E.png)
The CSV file has 200 SKUs as test data.

Required Payload:

```
{
  "reference": "${reference}",
  "basket": {
    "type": "STANDARD",
    "summary": {
      "totalItems": 3,
      "totalBasketValue": 360,
      "totalDiscountAmount": {
        "staff": 0,
        "general": 0,
        "promotions": 0
      },
      "totalTaxAmount": 60
    },
    "contents": [
      {
        "sku": "10001",
        "description": "sku description should be here",
        "itemUnitCost": 100,
        "itemUnitMetric": null,
        "itemUnitCount": 1,
        "totalUnitCost": 100,
        "totalUnitCostAfterDiscount": 100,
        "taxAmount": 20,
        "taxRate": 20,
        "qualifies": {
          "discount": true,
          "points": true
        }
      },
      {
        "sku": "10002",
        "description": "sku description should be here",
        "itemUnitCost": 100,
        "itemUnitMetric": null,
        "itemUnitCount": 1,
        "totalUnitCost": 100,
        "totalUnitCostAfterDiscount": 100,
        "taxAmount": 20,
        "taxRate": 20,
        "qualifies": {
          "discount": true,
          "points": true
        }
      },
      {
        "sku": "10003",
        "description": "sku description should be here",
        "itemUnitCost": 100,
        "itemUnitMetric": null,
        "itemUnitCount": 1,
        "totalUnitCost": 100,
        "totalUnitCostAfterDiscount": 100,
        "taxAmount": 20,
        "taxRate": 20,
        "qualifies": {
          "discount": true,
          "points": true
        }
      }
  ]
  }
}
```

Note: Above payload has 3 sku items (i.e., 10001, 10002, & 10003). I need to create payload with all 200 skus from the CSV file.

Creating new payload manually for 200 SKUs is time consuming and not efficient.

I looked at another solution posted here >>> [Build JSON Batches from CSV file with JMeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63080775/build-json-batches-from-csv-file-with-jmeter)
I couldnt make it work.

Provided screenshots is what I tried:
[Dummy Sampler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0AiT.png) [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/em8mT.png)[View Results Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4KY7.png)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need any CSV file for this, it's possible to generate incrementing numbers in the given range in Groovy using i.e. [Number.upto()](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Number.html#upto(java.lang.Number,%20groovy.lang.Closure)) function.

Something like:

```
def payload = [:]

payload.put('reference', vars.get('reference'))

def basket = [:]
basket.put('type', 'STANDARD')
def summary = [:]
summary.put('totalItems', 3)
summary.put('totalBasketValue', 360)
def totalDiscountAmount = [:]
totalDiscountAmount.put('staff', 0)
totalDiscountAmount.put('general', 0)
totalDiscountAmount.put('promotions', 0)
summary.put('totalDiscountAmount', totalDiscountAmount)
summary.put('totalTaxAmount', 60)
basket.put('summary', summary)

def contents = []

10001.upto(10201, { index ->
    def sku = [:]
    sku.put('sku', index as String)
    sku.put('description', 'sku description should be here')
    sku.put('itemUnitCost', 100)
    sku.put('itemUnitMetric', null)
    sku.put('itemUnitCount', 1)
    sku.put('totalUnitCost', 100)
    sku.put('totalUnitCostAfterDiscount', 100)
    sku.put('taxAmount', 20)
    sku.put('taxRate', 20)
    sku.put('qualifies', [discount: true, points: true])
    contents.add(sku)
})

basket.put('contents', contents)
payload.put('basket', basket)
vars.put('payload', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(payload).toPrettyString())
```

More information:

- [Apache Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html)
- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Comment: Thank you Dmitri!
You are a God sent.

Could you also show how to create paylod using CSV file please as per my original query?
I sometimes have requirements to use test data on CSV file which may not always have sequential numeric order of increment.

I tried putting csv file via CSV Data Set Config and gave variable name 'sku'.
Then, I tried to put the variable in the code like: 
sku.put('sku', '${sku}')
But, instead of parameterizing sku's in sequential order. I am getting same sku printed on all 200 of the blocks. 

Regards!